# D3 multiplying datapoints in stackedAreaChart

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, nvd3.js

For some reason my stackedAreaChart is multiplying each of my y values by 10. Here's what I have so far:

```
  var data = [{"key":"New York","values":[["2000","47"],["2001","49"],["2002","49"],["2003","47"],["2004","48"],["2005","49"],["2006","50"],["2007","48"],["2008","48"],["2009","47"],["2010","50"],["2011","49"],["2012","51"]]},{"key":"Los Angeles","values":[["2000","56"],["2001","55"],["2002","55"],["2003","56"],["2004","57"],["2005","56"],["2006","57"],["2007","56"],["2008","57"],["2009","57"],["2010","57"],["2011","55"],["2012","56"]]}] ;

  var colors = d3.scale.category10();
  keyColor = function(d, i) {return colors(d.key)};

  var chart;
  nv.addGraph(function() {
    chart = nv.models.stackedAreaChart()
    .x(function(d) { return d[0] })
    .y(function(d) { return d[1] })
    .color(keyColor)

    chart.xAxis
    .showMaxMin(false)

    chart.yAxis
    .tickFormat(d3.format(',.2f'));

    d3.select('#chart1')
    .datum(data)
    .transition().duration(500).call(chart);

    nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);

    chart.dispatch.on('stateChange', function(e) { nv.log('New State:', JSON.stringify(e)); });

    return chart;
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The values in your `data` array are all strings. Somewhere inside nvd3 world, these are getting added up as strings, not numbers, and then you get the problem you're experiencing (e.g. `"47" + "49"` equals `"4749"`).

The quick way to fix it is to change your accessor to `.y(function(d) { return +d[1] })`. The added `+` coerces the string into a number.

But the better fix is to start out with numbers – rather than strings – in your JSON.